# PDO rollback is not working

Tags: php

I want to see effect of rollback.But every time when I run the code the table is getting deleted even if I have called rollback.
I have following code

```
    <?php 
    define('DBNAME','test');
    define('DBUSER','root');
    define('DBHOST','localhost');
    define('PASS','');

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.DBHOST.';dbname='.DBNAME,DBUSER,PASS);

    /* Begin a transaction, turning off autocommit */
    $dbh->beginTransaction();

    $sth = $dbh->prepare("DROP TABLE calendar2");
     $result = $sth->execute();

    /* Change the database schema and data */
    if(!$result )
        $dbh->commit();
    else
        $dbh->rollback();

    ?>
```

Comment: You should check that you are using INNODB as your database type. MyISAM does not support transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: Not all databases will allow transactions to operate on DDL statements: some will generate errors, whereas others (including MySQL) will automatically commit the transaction after the first DDL statement has been encountered. -- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php

Database definition language (DDL) statement such as `DROP TABLE` or `CREATE TABLE`, in MySQL, cannot be used within transactions.

> Some databases, including MySQL, automatically issue an implicit `COMMIT` when a database definition language (DDL) statement such as `DROP TABLE` or `CREATE TABLE` is issued within a transaction. The implicit `COMMIT` will prevent you from rolling back any other changes within the transaction boundary. -- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.rollback.php

So when a DDL statement is issued it's like calling `commit()` immediately after the DDL statement. You can't rollback the DDL statement, and because `commit()` is called implicitly you also can't rollback anything before the DDL statement.